# DIV position absolute causes other elements after the div to be hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the following style

```css
#holder{
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-color: #DCE1E5;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    padding:8px;
}
```

My issues is that any element I enter after this div tag is hidden behind the div for example

```
<div id="holder">My Stuff here of</div>
<div id="somethingelse">This will be hidden behind the top div</div>
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this, and have it be IE7 compatible?

Comment: Put #holder back in the flow so it won't overlap other elements.  Or absolute position the other elements.  Or absolute position the div within a container and put the other divs in a different container.  What you are describing is not a problem but a lack of understanding of how absolute functions I  think.

Answer (score 2):

**position: absolute;** removes the element from the flow defined by the box model. Any element that is smaller that **holder** will be hidden by it. The solution is not to use **position: absolute;** for that case, since I understand that you are not really wanting something that can be achieved through this.

I would recommend that you take a time to understand what box model is: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 1):

When you absolutely position an element, it is removed from the normal document flow and placed at the point you specify. All of the other items continue to follow the normal flow of the document, which means that some of them may be positioned at the same place as the absolutely-positioned element.

To fix this, you can adopt one of two approaches:

Don't absolutely position `#holder`. This will allow it to remain in the normal document flow and play well with the other elements.

or

Provide appropriate margins to position the other elements away from `#holder`.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 have to set z-index property for any elements with position relative or absolute.

**CSS**

```
#holder{
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
display:block;
padding:8px;
margin-top: 1px;
background-color: #DCE1E5;
z-index: 1;}

#somethingelse {
position: relative;
top: 40px;
z-index: 1000;
```

}

DEMO is here: http://jsfiddle.net/B3jZ5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should try `position: relative;` instead of absolute in next div.

Answer (score 0):

This is a z-indexing issue. You can override this behavior by assigning a z-index value to the various elements. And forewarning, IE7 assigns any element with the "position" style a z-index value, so it may take some testing to get it to work correctly. You usually have to assign the z-index to parent elements to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify top and left for your absolute element.
`somethingelse` element is behind your `holder`.

Either remove the background color to view `#somethingelse` or assign a z-index to both elements. Then you can see both elements are overlapped.
Also you can add opacity or make holder position to be relative.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the #holder DIV to have an "absolute" position, that means that you are taking it out of the regular flow of elements on the page. Thus, all the other elements will flow up to take the place of it.  There could be many solutions, based on your end goal.  However, just with what you have given us, you can fix the problem by changing the position to "relative".

Answer (score 0):

add top to somethingelse element if position is absolute.

top : the height of #holder

or margin-top :  the height of #holder if #holder element is floated like float:left or right;